# Laravel foreach json column query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run a foreach loop to query data within a json data column in my DB. I believe the foreach code is correct, but I cant retrieve data using the loop. I trying to use eloquent queries if possible.

Data stored in column named 'figuresinorder' : ["1","22","2","45"]

```
            $items = ['1', '2', '3'];
            $figures3 = customtrades::where(function ($query) use ($items) {
                foreach($items as $item) {
                  $query->whereJsonContains('figuresinorder', "$item");
                }
            })
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to remove the `"` surrounding `$item`,

```
$query->whereJsonContains('figuresinorder', $item);
```

If that doesn't work, try this instead:

```
$query->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(figuresinorder, ?)', [$item]);
```

Comment: I still have no joy with both statements, I it baffling me because if i change $item to a number e.g.

```
 $query->whereJsonContains('figuresinorder', '1');
```

I get a returned result, so I have no idea why using the variable is not working.

Comment: if you pass it through " ", it will get  $item a string and no values have been changed

Comment: thanks for your feedback and help, I am not sure what you mean by pass through " ".